# Bootstrapping complex data sets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The application I am working on has "Default lists" one of which is already created in the app currently. The list has events and events touch 2-3 other models. **Which would make seeding, etc very time consuming due to the complexity of the lists and the associated models the list has data in**

Due to the complexity of the lists I would prefer to build the lists though the UI and then extracting it for later use.

Is there any worthwhile way of extracting the aforementioned list object and for lack of a better term "bootstrap it"

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://github.com/rhalff/seed_dump

I highly enjoy the comments on the github page

> It mainly exists for people who are too lazy writing create statements
>   in db/seeds.rb themselves and need something (seed_dump) to dump data
>   from the table(s) into seeds.rb

My response to that is "work smart, not hard" no need for me to spend a day or 2 writing out long seeds instead of doing actual work.

Unless i'm hungover then i'll just pretend seed_dump is on the fritz ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to get at is seed data. Take a look at this [railscats](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) on just that.

Comment: I'm familiar with seed data and bootstrapping data to an application. However, what I was getting at is - "Due to the complexity of the lists I would prefer to build the lists though the UI and then extracting it for later use."

Comment: Like building a rails app, enter data via form, perhaps persisting the data to file instead of storing it in a DB? Maybe write it as JSON to a file or maybe store it in a mongo/couch backend!?